# How to find the last time a particular report was run

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using SSRS 2016. I want to find out the last time a particular report was run. Is this something I can easily query on the ReportServer database?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this from the executionlog tables/views in the ReportServer database. By default this will have (I think) 60 days of logs. You can change this value in the ReportServer properties. I have 400 days retention so I can report on report usage.

Anyway, you can use something like this...

```
USE ReportServer
GO

select TOP 1
    c.*
    , el.*
from ExecutionLog el
    join Catalog c on el.ReportID = c.ItemID
WHERE 
    c.[Path] = '/MyReportFolder/MyReportSubFolder' 
    and c.[Name] = 'MyReportName'
ORDER BY TimeStart DESC
```

The `path =...` is optional if all your report names are unique and the `top 1` is there because you asked to only find the last time the report was run but you can obviously remove these limitations.

Comment: Thanks for the info. quick followup question, we are using the default of 60 days as you mentioned. I ran a count with the query to see how many rows total we have for 60 days and it was 46,000. We would like more history like you have but I'm wondering if that will grow the DB too big or cause some other issue, any thoughts on this?

Comment: Even at 400 days that would only be roughly 306,000 records which is nothing really.